# Would UK visa/entry problems affect getting a visa for other countries?

Tags: visa, marriage, new-zealand, overstay

Long story short. Unfortunately, I was removed from the UK by the authorities. I understand that there is definitely going to be a ban on me to the UK. Am I liable to get visa from other countries denied on the basis of that ban (such as New Zealand, Canada or the USA)?

My main concern is to find out whether New Zealand would ban me since my fiance is from New Zealand. Is there going to be an issue in getting a NZ visa because of a possible ban from the UK?

Answer (score 3):

All of the countries you've listed require that you disclose your immigration history, including removals, refusals, and bans. Not doing so is a bad idea, and can result in visa denials, refusals, bans.

New Zealand is the same: you have to reveal your UK history and removal or risk not being issued a visa.

You noted on SETravel that you do not have a fiance in New Zealand but, rather, there is an individual who may be willing to marry. Culturally arranged marriage visas are issued by New Zealand.

[New Zealand Immigration](https://www.immigration.govt.nz/new-zealand-visas/apply-for-a-visa/criteria/culturally-arranged-marriage-visitor-visa?nationality=nationality-IND&country=residence-IND&applying=no) requires that you submit your passport (which may show the UK removal) and demonstrate your character (provide a Police Certificate from your home country, as well as from any country in which you lived for a year or more; that would include the UK).

You also have to prove that you've met (as well as her immigration status, among other things). Is she planning to meet you outside of New Zealand?

For your broad question, whether information is shared among countries such as the UK, Canada, the US, New Zealand, Australia, the answer is yes: all of these countries share intelligence information. No one knows what, or how much. Is immigration information shared? Who knows? Could be, but the bottom line is don't let that affect where you apply for a visa, or what you do or don't include in an application. Failing to disclose the facts, lying may result in visa refusals and can mean that you're not going anywhere for a long time.

Comment: @Dorthy, thanks for your time and response. However, could you respond further to my queries please. – You know my situation for now in regards to person willing to marry. But if we do get married in India, how long and how exactly do we need to live together as it might be hard for her to live with me for a year or two in India because of her job and stuff. -- furthermore, there's no problem myself getting police clearing from India. But I'm not sure of UK is going to issue me a clear police clearance as I was removed from there because of overstaying.

Comment: So are they (UK) going to clear my police report from there because I never got involved in any kind of illegal activities of any sort all my life there and here. -- yes, she's going to come to India to meet me and to see if we are compatible for each other, which if yes, then will get married here too -- and yes thanks for your genuine suggestion in regards to further immigration.

Comment: @Truth You have to follow the rules of the country to which you want to emigrate. If NZ requires that you document your relationship and obtain a police certificate from the UK, then that's what you'll have to do if you want to live in that country. You've asked the same question on SE Travel and SE Expats and received cogent feedback. Because of your UK removal, you might wish to engage an immigration solicitor. We don't chats here, so let's not go back and forth; restating the same question does not change the response.